# store new entity with foreign relation

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

Noob question:

I have modelA called 'locations' which has a column called 'id'. 
I have modelB called 'assets' which also has a column called 'id'.

On ModelB i want to keep track of what location it is associated with so i have a column called 'location_id' and the foreign key is set.

My question is.. on my controller for ModelB.. when im receiving the information, is the attribute on the API suppose to be called "location_id"? because what ive seen only is to name it "locationId" without the underscore. but this creates a problem because that isnt what the column is named..

thanks

tried looking through docs on eloquent relationships but couldnt find anything that answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
class ModelB
{
    protected $fillable = ['location_id', ...];

    public function location() 
    {
        // Assuming ModelA is a Location class.
        // The default parameters of belongsTo will search for `location_id`.
        // You can pass custom parameters if you have another column.
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelA::class);
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve your ModelB using `ModelB::find(1)` (gets ID 1) or similar code.

```
$model = ModelB::find(1);
$location = $model->location;

// These 2 calls return the same value, although the second one retrieves it through the relation,
// which means an extra query is called if the `location` relation is not loaded yet.
$locationId = $model->location_id;
$locationId = $model->location->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want the field name coming in to match what is on the model where possible (so `location_id`).  This makes life a lot easier as you can automatically pull information directly from a `$request` object, match to the db field, etc.

So, as a possible example, you might have a field coming in from a a web source (API, form, etc) where you have several fields, including `location_id`.  If your method pulls using a `Request` object, you could do a `save` or `update` without having any more code than:

```
  $newAsset = Asset::create($request->all());
```

What you might be confusing this with slightly is the method or relationship on your **Asset** model for the related **Location**.  This you may wish to name `location` (no `id`).  With this, you can simply pull the location from the asset:  `$asset->location->name`

HTH